# maven not found on heroku - how to run my java app?

Tags: java, maven, heroku

Simple as that, I am trying to deploy this app https://github.com/pac4j/spark-pac4j-demo to my heroku instance.

I can run it locally with: `mvn compile exec:java`

But on heroku, there is no maven installed:

```
2016-04-12T18:34:21.074629+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `mvn compile exec:java`
2016-04-12T18:34:23.303776+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: mvn: command not found
2016-04-12T18:34:23.303620+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
```

I have no clue how to set all the class paths per hand. I would appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first need to vendor your dependencies (i.e. copy them into the `target/` directory). You can do so by adding this to your `pom.xml`:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then the correct command to run the app will probably be something like `java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main` (where `Main` should be replaced with your class that contains the `public static void main` method).

Here is a [sample app using Spark](https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started/) so you can see how this all comes together.

Maven is not a good way to run an application in production. It creates an additional dependency for your app and adds layers of indirection to the process execution.

Comment: Thanks! that is very helpul. Can you specify the command to run my app if my main class is inside a package? e.g. org.pac4j.demo.spark

Comment: You would simply pre-pend the package name like: `java -cp ... org.pac4j.demo.spark.Main`